# Embedding in New Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

How can I put even one location on the new Google Maps?

The old version offered the embed icon.

Where is the embed code now?

Comment: Check [this link](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/applications/quick-tip-embedding-new-google-maps/).

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're asking is how to get an embedable version of a map from http://maps.google.com

The link for an embedable map is down at the bottom, inside the gear icon:
[image: Maps Gear Icon]

After that, click on the **Embed map** tab at the top:

[image]

From there you can copy the source HTML for the map